# timeit returns keyerror when deleting from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, timeit

I am doing an exercise that compares the execution time for `del` operator on lists and dictionaries. Here is the code for that:

```
from timeit import Timer
import random

random.seed(a = 42)
n_exec = 10_000

print("Total time for {} executions".format(n_exec))
for n in range(100_000, 500_000, 25_000):
    t_list = Timer("del x_list[int(0.9 * {})]".format(n), "from __main__ import n, x_list")
    x_list = list(range(n))
    time_list = t_list.timeit(number = n_exec)

    t_dict = Timer("del x_dict[int(0.9 * {})]".format(n), "from __main__ import n, x_dict")
    x_dict = {i:i*3 for i in range(n)}
    time_dict = t_dict.timeit(number = n_exec)

    print("n = {0:6d} -> list = {1:7.6f}, dict = {2:7.6f}".format(n, time_list, time_dict))
```

But I get a keyerror when timing the execution time for dictionary.

```
Total time for 10000 executions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timeit_del.py", line 16, in <module>
    time_dict = t_dict.timeit(number = n_exec)
  File "C:\Users\kesha\Anaconda3\lib\timeit.py", line 178, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
KeyError: 90000
```

Why is this key error occurring when the key is clearly available in the dictionary? I think the key is a part of the dictionary because I changed the operation being timed from `del` to `print` and the expected values were printed to the console.

**Edit**: Thanks to  Patrick Haugh, I know that running `timeit` 10,000 times is not possible because timeit runs the same code again and again without repeating the setup, so the second run doesn't find the key deleted on the previous run, raising a `KeyError`. I tried to average the performance time using a for loop which is a very bad idea, because for loops are extremely slow. Calling a function that creates a dictionary within it's scope and does the `del` operation is another idea but that would probably add a bunch of overhead to the results.

Anyway the point was knowing that for dict `del` is an O(1) operation but for lists the thing is an O(n) operation. Thanks for all the advice.

Comment: `timeit` runs the same operation multiple times to reduce error.  If you delete a key from the dict in the first run, then that key is absent from the dictionary in the next run.

Comment: Thanks! I tried with `n_exec = 1` and that worked. I thought I'd replace `Timer.timeit` call with `time_dict = t_dict.repeat(repeat = n_exec, number = 1)` but that didn't work either. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Is creating 10,000 dicts and calling timeit on each of them the way to go here?